# How can I generate a dictionary from a list?

Tags: f#

How can I generate a dictionary from a list?

**Take the following list:**

```
let numbers = [1;2;2;3;3;3;4;5;5;]
```

How can I generate a dictionary where the key is the element and the value is the number of times that the element occurs within the list?

**My sad attempt:**

```
let numbers = [1;2;2;3;3;3;4;5;5;]
numbers |> Seq.fold (fun accumulator element -> Map.add (element, element list???) 0)
```

Comment: **hint**: I would have a look at `List/Seq.groupBy` and [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549277(v=vs.100).aspx) (you can use a `Map` too - but you asked for a Dictionary and this is indeed a bit faster)

Comment: @Carsten, Sorry, when I wrote my reply, your comment was not yet :(

Comment: @FoggyFinder hey no problem - Answers are bigger then stupid comments ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Seq.groupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)

```
let numbers = [1;2;2;3;3;3;4;5;5]

let map = numbers |> Seq.groupBy id |> Map.ofSeq 

map |> Map.iter (printfn "%A - %A")
```

**Print:**

```
1 - seq [1]
2 - seq [2; 2]
3 - seq [3; 3; 3]
4 - seq [4]
5 - seq [5; 5]
```

**Link:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/xyNyzn

**Edit:**

If you want to get : number - frequency (now using Seq.fold :))

```
let addElement (acc:Map<int,int>) element = 
    if acc.ContainsKey element then acc.Add(element, acc.[element] + 1) 
    else acc.Add(element, 1)

(Map.empty, numbers)
||> Seq.fold (addElement)
|> Map.iter (printfn "%A - %A")
```

**Print:**

```
1 - 1
2 - 2
3 - 3
4 - 1
5 - 2
```

**Link:**

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yFw4Jq

Comment: nice one - it's accepted so it's ok - but I would have suspected that Scott wanted to have a map to `Seq.length` in there for the values ^^

Comment: The frequency calculation is needlessly complicated. Just `Seq.length` would do.

Comment: @Carsten, Thank you. Really =) I added another variant.

Comment: I'm adding a different question regarding the max value in another question in about 5 minutes. I know how to do all of this in C#. But F# is just alien to me.

Comment: @Scott Nimrod, If you have a small question, you can ask in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f Perhaps, it is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code uses `Map`, but, assuming `Dictionary` like you said, such a function could be written:

```
Seq.countBy id >> dict
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use the ">>"? Because I get results only through Seq.countBy id |> dict https://dotnetfiddle.net/H5d9wU

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand